# Is the set of Perron vectors of rank-1 matrix majorizers convex?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a non-negative symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, and let $\mathbb{R}_n^+$ be the set of non-negative $n$-columns. Is the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}_n^+: x\cdot x^T-A\succeq0\}$ convex? Here $\succeq0$ means "positive semidefinite".

Comment: In fact, it is.

Comment: @ MikeGoubko Care to post the solution then?

Comment: Let $x$ and $y$ be in the set. This means that for any $z\in \mathbb{R}_n$ $z^Txx^Tz\ge z^TAz$, so $x^Tz\ge\sqrt{z^TAz}$, and the same is true for $y$. For $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y$, where $\alpha\in [0,1]$, write $$z^T(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)^Tz=(\alpha x^Tz+(1-\alpha)y^Tz)^2\ge$$ $$\ge (\alpha \sqrt{z^TAz}+(1-\alpha)\sqrt{z^TAz})^2=z^TAz.$$ (The proof is due to V. Korepanov)

Comment: Ups, we may take the square root only if $z^TAz\ge 0$. But for $z^TAz<0$ the desired inequality trivially holds, since the left-hand side is non-negative.